# Upload and display image in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

So I followed this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b696c4/how-to-upload-and-display-image-in-mvc/ given by @Div and it just gave me errors at    `ContentRepository service = new ContentRepository();`. How am I suppose to replace that with something else that contain `UploadImageInDataBase` like   `int i = service.UploadImageInDataBase(file, model);` ?

```
Private readonly DBContext db = new DBContext();
```

Gives me error "is inaccessible due to its protection level." And it wont be usable since it gives error "Cannot resolve", but I replaced it with  `private TestEntities db = new TestEntities();` and it works then. Hopefully it will cover everything?

I cant add anything inside `var Content = new Content {` as I getting "Cant resolve symbol X" inside it.

Then at

```
List<ImageVm> contentModel = content.Select(item => new ImageVm()) {
```

I'm getting following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable'
>   to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I followed every step carefully and I can't get any further. 
The author basically just said "add this code" without explanation and I've no idea how to solve it.

Any idea how to solve it or have any better guides?

Comment: @Div I made it public,  same error.

Comment: @Div okay I deleted it. Thanks looking forward for it.

Comment: That link it self gives a source code. have you checked that?

Comment: @Div Oh I missed it.... Got the source code now. Will check it and try cover the errors. Will update if it doesn't go well.

Comment: OK, sure, in that example, they are using `CKEditor`

Comment: @Div it wont work in my project, same issue as I stated before. I'm using database first, is that maybe the issue?

Comment: *I'm using database first, is that maybe the issue* That example is for code first only

Comment: @Div I see, I manage to fix `ContentRepository`. The only remaining is this part: `"List<ImageVm> contentModel = content.Select(item => new ImageVm()) {"`, as I stated in question. And everything inside gets "`cant resolve symbol X`" etc. Is it possible to solve this for database first?

Comment: *everything inside gets* Did not get, what do you mean?

Comment: @Div Nevermind, got it all working now. It wasn't hard but very tricky as I had to search everywhere in his project to figure how things worked. E.g. these code wasn't in same class file etc. would be much better if author could added some comments or explanation. Thanks for your help, it was a good learning challenge :)